# Laplace transform of $\log(\log X) $

Tags: laplace-transform

How could I find the Laplace transform of the function $ \log(\log(x)) $? This function is not tabulated ?

Comment: The (usual, ones-sided) Laplace transform requires the function be defined on $(0,\infty)$.  The function $\log \log x$ is not defined on $(0,1]$, so some modification either to the function or to the transform is needed.  What modification(s) is/are acceptable?

Comment: i thought that if we can define the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty}dt (log(x))^{n}exp(-sx) = g(s,n) $ the takijng the derivative with respecto to 'n0 at n=0 would work

Comment: The question would make sense for $\log|\log x|$ (for instance).